# Adding a belt hole without a leather punch

Tags: substitute-tool, clothing

I don't want to invest in a leather hole punch, so how could I add an extra hole (or some other solution)?

Comment: I'll assume gaining weight isn't the solution you're looking for....

Comment: More than losing weight, believe it or not.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use a power drill with a small drill bit the size of the hole you want.  Put a piece of scrap wood under the belt first. After the drill bit penetrates the belt, move the drill up and down to clear out the chaff from the edges of the hole.

(if you don't own a drill, you could go to your local home depot - they often have test drills...be discrete....or...somewhere near you a neighbor probably has one)

Comment: If using a power drill, be aware that the belt might start rotating when you get through it. Keep it properly fastened whilst drilling the extra hole!

Comment: A Forstner bit (sp?) Will give you a clean hole.

Comment: Remember that the faster you go, the cleaner cut you get, in this case. Also, be sure to get a very sharp drill.

Comment: You deserve a cookie for this.

Comment: I've used used this technique with and Battery Hand Drill, use a "wood bit" not a metal bit for best results.

Answer (score 26):

I used to use a heated nail. Simply, hold it with pliers, and heat its tip up for a minute or so on the stove fire. Keep your belt stretched firmly (you can hold one side of the belt under you foot, and the other side with one of your hand, while the other hand is holding the pliers) and point the nail to the spot you want to make a hole, and push into the belt. It makes a small regular hole very easily.

[image]

I see many sources on the web mention the nail with a hammer. No need for a hammer, heated nail held firmly with pliers, can make the hole you want.

Comment: Based on my personal experience, **this** the best answer, its faster, easier, and most cost effective(if you ruin anything it would be only the nail, no drills, no knifes, no scissors)

Comment: This also works if you heat the nails up in the oven if you have an electric stovetop. **400 degrees** for **3-5 minutes** should do the trick. Just place the nails in an oven safe dish or foil boat.

Answer (score 5):

Careful usage of a sharp pointed knife can easily cut you another hole in your leather belt.

Mark out where you want the new hole, and put the knife at the marker and rotate gently. Soon you'll have your extra hole.

In fact most thingies with a sharp point can be used if you are in a real pinch. I.e. one end of scissors, kitchen knives, screw drivers, or even a key if you are a little persistent! Of course the sharper the better...

Comment: @DangerZone And make sure you're not wearing the belt when trying to create a hole!
I once saw in the news, that a girl got her stomach sliced, because they tried to add a hole to the belt with a kitchen knife **while she was wearing it**.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of shops will punch one for you.

You could go to a shoe repair shop or a menswear shop and ask if they can punch the hole for you.

Comment: It is lacking the _lifehack_:P

Answer (score 2):

i used a screwdriver bit in an electric screw driver. worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

Melted a screw banged it in tongue belt with a hammer holding the screw with garden shears that don't work and done deal......my husband thinks I got the neighbour who is a pro DIY to do it !!!!!!!

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don’t understand “melted”

Answer (score 1):

For many years, I've used the awl point found on many multitools (*vis.* Leatherman) and multiblade pocket knives.  I just use pressure on the belt's metal tongue to make a mark, then take off the belt and drill through with the awl point by rotating back and forth.  Once it pierces through, a few additional rotation strokes will enlarge the hole enough for the tongue to push through readily, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use the pointed end of scissors for punching a hole into my belt.

Once, it manages to pierce to the other end, start rotating it, while simultaneously drilling in; until the hole of desired size(or diameter) is punched in.

If the scissors isn't sharp enough, then using the hack suggested by @Hawk